# Drupal versus with Omni Update: Should I move from Drupal to Omni Update?

Tags: theming, updating

**Use Case**

- Current (aging) IT website built on Drupal 5.
- Most people hate this website because the theme is awful and adding content is painful.
- An upgrade to Drupal 6 and a theme / module updates are what are needed. (Not considering Drupal 7 until more modules are available.)
- Some of our leadership thinks we need to switch platforms anyway.

**Argument**

- What are the pros of sticking with Drupal versus switching to Omni Update?
- What are some pro Drupal buzzwords that nontechnical manager-folk will understand?
- What is your best argument for selling Drupal to a prospective client?

Answer (score 1):

I think you might have answered your own question: "it will turn into a LOT of work if they decide to switch to the proprietary platform". Work = time = money, and that is manager-speak.

Answer (score 0):

> What are the pros of sticking with Drupal vs. switching to Omni
>   Update?

There is a site called http://drupal.stackexchange.com, but there is no http://omniupdate.stackexchange.com. Just kidding of course, but still, there's some truth behind this - I bet that Drupal has better support than a proprietary platform.

Now we're waiting for Drupal 8; this means we have a lot of people with good knowledge about 6 who could perform the upgrade fine (maybe some reading is needed, but still). Show the managers the difference between "stock" Drupal 5 vs. 6 vs. 7. Try to show them some of the developments underway. Show them the big guys doing crazy stuff with Drupal; mention Acquia for example, show Gardens. Mention that Drupal is good enough for Ubuntu sites, for the Twitter dev site and so on.

If none of the above works, just mention that **it's waaaaaay cheaper to perform an upgrade** than to move to a proprietary software. Perhaps even if you have to pay for other guys to do the upgrade, because you will have to move content anyway and it's easier (= less workhours) with a Drupal upgrade.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I have already performed the upgrade to Drupal 6, this is about communicating the value to the project stakeholders. It really is a time issue too, it would take 700-1000 hours to transfer to a new system and I'm offering something upgraded _right now_